# How do I filter deep associations in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have the following tables: binders, docs, users, docs_users. Doc belongsTo Binder, Doc hasAndBelongsToMany User.

I want to get binders and their associated docs for the user that is currently logged in (the associated user_id in the docs_users table).

I have tried Containable and find('all') with joins, conditions, etc. but I can't figure out how to remove the Docs that are from Users who are not associated in the docs_users table.

This code does NOT work:

```
$binders = $this->Binder->find( 
        'all',                  
        array( 
            'joins' => array(
                array( 
                    'table' => 'binders_users', 
                    'alias' => 'BindersUser', 
                    'type' => 'inner', 
                    'foreignKey' => false, 
                    'conditions'=> array(
                        'BindersUser.binder_id = Binder.id',
                        'BindersUser.user_id = ' . $this->Auth->user('id')
                    )
                ),
                array( 
                    'table' => 'docs', 
                    'alias' => 'Doc', 
                    'type' => 'left', 
                    'foreignKey' => false, 
                    'conditions'=> array(
                        'Doc.binder_id = Binder.id',
                    )
                ),                          
                array( 
                    'table' => 'docs_users', 
                    'alias' => 'DocsUser', 
                    'type' => 'left', 
                    'foreignKey' => false, 
                    'conditions'=> array(
                        'DocsUser.doc_id = Doc.id',
                        'DocsUser.user_id = ' . $this->Auth->user('id')
                    )
                )           
            ),
            'recursive'=>0
        )
    );
$this->set('binders', $binders);
```

And neither does this:

```
$this->Binder->recursive = 2;
$this->Binder->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$this->Binder->contain(array(
    'Branch',
    'Doc' => array(                     
        'User' => array(
            'DocsUser' => array(
                'conditions' => array('id = "17"')
            )
        )
    )
));
$binders = $this->Binder->find('all');
```

Any help from you seasoned pros would be great! Thanks!

**Alternative/Simplified Solutions?**

This works if I just want to get binders to which users have permissions. Short and sweet. However, it will still send ALL associated docs through, which is NOT the behavior I want. It needs to only pass on the docs to which the user has permissions (as described previously).

```
$binders = $this->Binder->find( 
    'all',                  
    array( 
        'joins' => array(
            array( 
                'table' => 'binders_users', 
                'alias' => 'BindersUser', 
                'type' => 'inner', 
                'foreignKey' => false, 
                'conditions'=> array(
                    'BindersUser.binder_id = Binder.id',
                    'BindersUser.user_id = ' . $this->Auth->user('id')
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: It might help if you set `debug` to 2 and look at what query cake is generating. Then make the changes required to get your desired result.

Comment: Also, could you paste your DB schema on pastebin or something and link it.

Comment: Good idea. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/0bRn9USD I'm not using the ACL tables right now because I think doing that at a record-level would create a massive database. Kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: If @Leo's approach doesn't work for you, why not just break it into two queries to get the exact output you want? I find that when working with Cake and $this->find(), I tend to forget the fact that it's all SQL in the end and that you can always break down the problem instead of doing it all in one query :)

Comment: JohnP - You're right. I just don't know how to accomplish this within the framework of CakePHP yet. Still a little green.

Comment: Why not just get all the docs that belong to this user? That will give you the binders if you have your recursive level at 1, I should think. Try that out

Comment: @JohnP I'm trying to display different folders/documents based on the group of the user. The other find() and paginate() calls are within the Binder context so I want to try and keep it the same rather than creating a bunch of functions/views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the final solution I came up with based on all of the great feedback I got. I think this is an elegant solution that can be reused in any scenario where deep associations are required.

In the binder_controller I unbound the Doc model, and bound it back using the finderQuery to select only the Docs that a user has permission to see. Then in joined the binders_users table selecting only the binders that users have permissions to.

*Thank you everyone for all your help!*

```
$this->Binder->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Doc')));
$this->Binder->bindModel(
    array('hasMany' => array(
            'Doc' => array(
                'className' => 'Doc',
                'foreignKey' => 'binder_id',
                'dependent' => false,
                'finderQuery' => 'SELECT Doc.* FROM docs AS Doc INNER JOIN docs_users AS DocsUser ON DocsUser.doc_id = Doc.id AND DocsUser.user_id = ' . $this->Auth->user('id')
            )
        )
    )
);

$binders = $this->Binder->find( 
    'all',                  
    array( 
        'joins' => array(
            array( 
                'table' => 'binders_users', 
                'alias' => 'BindersUser', 
                'type' => 'inner', 
                'foreignKey' => false, 
                'conditions'=> array(
                    'BindersUser.binder_id = Binder.id',
                    'BindersUser.user_id = ' . $this->Auth->user('id')
                )
            )               
        )
    )
);
```

More on [binding/unbinding models](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly)

Answer (score 5):

These are a few of the options available for doing deep finds on data in CakePHP:

- https://github.com/Terr/linkable/wiki
- http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations
- http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find

Comment: Those are great links. Definitely got me this far. But I'm not sure they truly answer the question. I think some related code would really help here.

Answer (score 0):

On this line, you need to tell Cake which Model's id you are talking about:

```
'conditions' => array('id = "17"')
```

e.g. `DocsUser.id`

...and you don't use recursive with containable. Get rid of it.

Comment: Actually that is specified by the array tree. If I just wanted it to be one level you're right, I could specify Doc.User.Docsuser.id = 17 but still, same problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried coming in from a user perspective?

```
$this->Binder->Doc->User->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$this->Binder->Doc->User->contain(array('Doc'=>'Binder'));
$user = $this->Binder->Doc->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>'User.id'=>$user_id));
```

The 'DocsUser' association should be detected anyway.

From a Binders perspective maybe

In your Binders MODEL add ( please check table, key and model names in case I made a typo  )

```
function getBindersByUserSql($user_id)
    {       
        $dbo = $this->getDataSource();
        $subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
            array(
                    'fields' => array('DISTINCT(Doc.binder_id)'),
                    'table' => "docs_users",                                       
                    'joins' => array(
                                array('table' => 'users',
                                    'alias' => 'User',
                                    'type' => 'INNER',
                                    'conditions' => array('DocsUser.user_id = User.id')
                                ),
                                array('table' => 'docs',
                                    'alias' => 'Doc',
                                    'type' => 'INNER',
                                    'conditions' => array('Doc.id = DocsUser.doc_id')
                                )
            ),
                    'alias'=>"DocsUser",                                            
                    'conditions' => array("User.id"=>$user_id),
                    'order' => null,
                    'group' => "Doc.binder_id"
                    ),
                    $this
                    );
        return $dbo->expression($subQuery);
    }
```

Then in your binders CONTROLLER try

```
$this->Binder->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$this->Binder->contain(array('Doc'));
$conditions = array();
$conditions = $this->Binder->getBindersByUserSql($this->Auth->user('id'));
$binders = $this->Binder->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions)));
```

Any good?

Comment: This is definitely on the right track. I guess the question is how do you do this in the context of a Binder?

Comment: So yeah. It works. Had to make a couple of changes (field names) but it works. Not to look a gift horse in the mouth but can you give me some hints about how I might approach displaying ALL binders for which the user has permissions, and the docs which belong to the binder, for which the user has permission. Thanks so much for your help. Super enlightening!

Comment: How are permissions represented?