# Find() Conditions with Deep Associations using Containable

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have the following three models `Product`, `Order`, `OrderDetail`.

`Product` has the following association:

```
public $hasMany = array('OrderDetail');
```

`Order` has the following association:

```
public $hasMany = array('OrderDetail');
```

`OrderDetail` has the following associations:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Order');
public $belongsTo = array('Product');
```

I am using the `Containable` behaviour and want to `find()` Products.

How can I use a field from the `Order` model in the conditions part of the find() call?

Something like this in my `Product` model:

```
$this->find('all', array('
    conditions' => array(
        'Order.order_date' => '2011-09-12'
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot acheive what you want this way. If you have a look at the queries Cake does you will see why. Containable does multiple queries then assembles them.

The easiest way to acheive what you want is to perform the query from the Order model point of view, as it's the model that you are filtering. If this is not an option see:

[See some ways to do it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266626/how-do-i-filter-deep-associations-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

Use the '**contain**' index to specify the **Order** model and the relevant conditions. Ensure you are using the **containable** behaviour on the **Product** model.

```
$this->find('all', array(
  'contain' => array(
    'Order' => array(
      'conditions' => array(
        'Order.order_date' => '2011-09-12'
      )
    )
  ),
));
```

Also, you may want to have a look at your model relationships. I think possibly you specified them wrong in the question.

Comment: This does not work, the Order.order_date cannot be used in the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

First merge the $belongsTo array to

```
public $belongsTo = array('Order', 'Product');
```

and try again